# CSS - position element over another inside a scrolling area

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position

I have the following html structure

```
<div id="scrolling-container">
    <div id="cover"></div>
    <div id="contents">
        A variable amount of iframes
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the base jsbin explaining the issue.](http://jsbin.com/ajapuc/3/edit)

I would like to be able to side-scroll #contents but I want it to be covered entirely by a transparent element (#cover) that I can use for click-detection and to allow easier side-scrolling on a tablet.

It should be possible to do this with css alone. `#cover { position:absolute,top:0,bottom:0,left:0,right:0}` seems like it would be the way to go here as that's a technique I've used dozens of times before, but with scrolling it does not stretch all the way to the right, but rather just to the tip of the initially visible scrolling area. As you scroll, it no longer covers the elements

[Here is a demonstration of the issue](http://jsbin.com/ajapuc/4/edit). Try scrolling the container and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Why are you against using JavaScript for this?

Comment: @apaul34208 I currently am but its hacky as all sin. The iframes in `#contents` take a while to redraw and each one redraws asynchronously. Currently I have no simple hook (though I can certainly create one) for when one finishes redrawing. In addition, this messes up viewmodel code with ui concerns and just feels icky overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the contents of the div to `position: relative` and then using a psuedo element to generate the cover:

Demo: http://jsbin.com/arajag/1/edit

CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#scrolling-container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
#contents {
  width: 400em;
  height: 10em;
  position: relative;
}

#contents:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML: Remove #cover

I know that there is a gap above and below the cover, that's because Chrome sets a margin before and after the contents. You should adjust for this anyway so I don't think it'll be an issue.

Comment: Pretty cool!  I fixed the margins by explicitly setting them on #contents and then inverting them on #contents::after.  http://jsbin.com/arajag/5/edit

Comment: @OldPro, Thank you, I didn't set them for the demo because the OP's margins are probably different from the browser defaults.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, If this is the answer, could you please award the bounty, thank you!

Comment: Here you go, didn't realize it didn't happen automatically (it does when the bounty expires)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

<strike>You could</strike>

<strike>You should</strike>

You can still, [totally drop that and use jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492),

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/gL48t/)

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = $('#contents').width();
    $('#cover').width(x);
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    var x = $('#contents').width();
    $('#cover').width(x);
});

$('#scrolling-container').scroll(function () {
    var x = $('#contents').width();
    $('#cover').width(x);
});
```

css

```
div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#scrolling-container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
#contents {
  width: 4000em;
  height: 10em;
}

#cover {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: blue;

}
```

Sorry about that, this should work as advertised.

Comment: You can and I currently am (though I didn't know about the resize event +1 for that) but for a variety of reasons I'd like to avoid it. The foremost however is that this is absolutely doable with css only when you do not use a scrolling area, it seems odd that introducing `overflow-x: scroll` would suddenly require javascript

Comment: I know its frustrating. I've run into the issue, working on simple two column layouts.

Comment: Hmm...Just tried this. The resize event - while it can be set on a particular element - will only fire when the entire window resizes

Answer (score 0):

Here you go http://jsbin.com/oquguh/1/edit , i made your #container div the one who handles scrolling.

Comment: But this hard codes the width then doesn't it? If width is determined by what actually goes inside of #contents (as I say, in my actual case it is a list of iframes) then I don't see how this would work.

Comment: well, you can't make something 100% width in css if parent width is not defined. Only way to do this is with javascript after content loads.

Comment: That's not true, `width: 100%` simply tells block elements to fill all available space horizontally, it is quite common to use it without a parent element width. In addition, I'm using position: absolute and pinning the corners, not setting width directly. Using this trick works perfectly well when you're ''not'' inside a scrolling element, it is only the scrolling that messes it up.

Comment: Yeah, but css can only transfer values from parent based on that parent's css properties. It can't calculate parent width which is relative to amount of content. And thats what width: 100%; does, tells it to set width based on parent's width and padding properties.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
#cover { 
  width: 400em;
  height: 20em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Is this what you meant??

Comment: This hard codes the width of `#cover` - I've hard coded the width of #contents in the example but, as I say, #contents is actually of variable width.